# select a part of string in R

Tags: r, regex, compare, substring

i have a column of strings that looks like this :

```
 Topology=o5-22i34-56o74-96i117-139o159-181i210-232o247-269i
 Topology=o4-26i35-57o77-99i119-138o161-183i216-238o248-270i
 Topology=o4-21i32-54o69-91i112-134o156-178i215-237o252-271i
 Topology=i20-42o65-84i105-127o158-180i212-234o249-271i     
 Topology=o5-27i39-61o76-98i118-140o151-173i194-213o
```

I want to get the first number after equal sign and the last number in the string. the output should be something like

```
    5,269
    4,270
    4,271
    20,271
    5,213
```

Answer (score 2):

```
v <- c("Topology=o5-22i34-56o74-96i117-139o159-181i210-232o247-269i", 
"Topology=o4-26i35-57o77-99i119-138o161-183i216-238o248-270i", 
"Topology=o4-21i32-54o69-91i112-134o156-178i215-237o252-271i", 
"Topology=i20-42o65-84i105-127o158-180i212-234o249-271i",
"Topology=o5-27i39-61o76-98i118-140o151-173i194-213o") 
sub("^Topology=.(\\d+)-.*-(\\d+).*$", "\\1,\\2", v)
# [1] "5,269"  "4,270"  "4,271"  "20,271" "5,213"
```

or

```
r <- regexec("^Topology=.(\\d+)-.*-(\\d+).*$", v)
m <- regmatches(v, m)
(mat <- do.call(rbind, lapply(m, "[", 2:3)))
#       [,1] [,2] 
# [1,] "5"  "269"
# [2,] "4"  "270"
# [3,] "4"  "271"
# [4,] "20" "271"
# [5,] "5"  "213"
```

Finally, if you want numeric data (instead of character/string data):

```
apply(mat, 2, as.numeric)
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    5  269
# [2,]    4  270
# [3,]    4  271
# [4,]   20  271
# [5,]    5  213
```

Answer (score 2):

**1)** This assumes `s` is a character vector with one such string per component.  The following one-liner extracts all strings of digits, turning each such string to numeric and then takes the first and last of each line. Finally it reshapes it into a matrix which is transposed.  `fn$sapply` allows us to use the formula notation for the function at the end:

```
> library(gsubfn)
> t(fn$sapply(strapply(s, "\\d+", as.numeric), ~ c(head(x, 1), tail(x, 1))))
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    5  269
[2,]    4  270
[3,]    4  271
[4,]   20  271
[5,]    5  213
```

**2)** If we want exactly a vector of comma separated strings then modify it to be:

```
> fn$sapply(strapply(s, "\\d+"), ~ sprintf("%s,%s", head(x, 1), tail(x, 1)))
[1] "5,269"  "4,270"  "4,271"  "20,271" "5,213"
```

**3)** Here is yet another variation. It gives a matrix of character strings:

```
> strapplyc(s, "(\\d+).*\\D(\\d+)", simplify = rbind)
     [,1] [,2] 
[1,] "5"  "269"
[2,] "4"  "270"
[3,] "4"  "271"
[4,] "20" "271"
[5,] "5"  "213"
```

**4)** Here is a variation of the second solution that does not use gsubfn.  (A non-gsubfn solution could be derived from the first solution in a similar manner.)

```
> sapply(strsplit(s,"\\D+"),
+          function(x) sprintf("%s,%s", head(Filter(nzchar, x), 1), tail(x, 1)))
[1] "5,269"  "4,270"  "4,271"  "20,271" "5,213"
```

The first 3 solutions use the [gsubfn](http://gsubfn.googlecode.com) package and all but the third use only simple regular expressions `"\\d+"` or `"\\D+"`.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly more general solution:

```
sub("^\\D*(\\d+)-.*-(\\d+)\\D*$", "\\1,\\2", v)
```